# Mixed Localizable arguments

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to set mixed localizable or not arguments ?

Short explaination :

For a method/class you can set

```
 [Localizable(false/true)]
```

But, Is it possible to achieve something like that (the goal is that Resharper manages in better way this case, yes I know for litterals) ?

```
private void Mixed(string localizablearg, string notlocalizablearg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LocalizableAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.localizableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is targeting to the all application elements so you can try

```
private void Mixed([Localizable(true)]string localizablearg, [Localizable(false)] string notlocalizablearg)
```

Comment: it is aimed mainly at properties. it makes the compiler create an entry in the assembly's resource file if set to true on a property. what will it do in this case?

Comment: So obvious, thanks... (never thought that attributes were able to target arguments)